# Restrict onEdit Script to the SourceSheet only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code works as it should, except when I try to edit the targetsheet, I get returned to the Sourcesheet. Any edit I try in the targetsheet takes me back to sourcesheet.

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named TOP UP NEEDED
// target sheet of move to named ONLINE RELOCATION

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('TOP UP NEEDED'), true);
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
if(s.getName() == "TOP UP NEEDED" && r.getColumn() == 18 && r.getValue() == true) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ONLINE RELOCATION");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
 }
}
```

I tried adding code below to 2nd last row to keep it on targetsheet, but no good

```
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('TOP UP NEEDED'), true);
```

I really only want the onEdit to work on the sourcesheet

Can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='TOP UP NEEDED')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==18 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("ONLINE RELOCATION");
    var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Player0 - will remember tags for next time

Comment: still working over Xmas - hope you have a great day merry xmas to you and family

Comment: xmas is just another day.

Comment: Cooper - code doesnt seem to fire onedit. I am using a checkbox in 18 as the value for TRUE. should that matter ?

Comment: I'll test it with a column of checkboxes in column18

Comment: Try it now.  `if(e.range.columnStart==18 && e.value=="TRUE") {`